# Preprocess XSL Stylesheet - include external documents

Tags: css, xml, xslt

I need to do a transform on a number of XML files. To do the transforms I have a folder of various xsl stylesheets. I need to to the transform using a Java parser and I do not control the content of any of the stylesheets.

The stylesheets reference eachother with `xsl:import` statements and they also include css style like so:

```
<style type="text/css">
    <xsl:value-of select="document('../../common/display.css')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</style>
```

Simplified example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:import href="../../common/functions.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>..</title>
                <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
                <style type="text/css">
                    <xsl:value-of select="document('../../common/display.css')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have managed to include all other xsl files by using the following stylesheet to do a first-pass processing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="xsl:include">
  <xsl:copy-of select="document(@href)/xsl:stylesheet/*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However I cannot figure out how to do the same for the css references. Is it even possible to evaluate the `xsl:value-of` to either get the value of the string within the call to `document()` or otherwise get the content of the external css file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing `xsl:include` the way you are doing it isn't correct acccording to the XSLT specification, for a number of reasons: the copied instructions will have in-scope namespaces different from the original, they will have different values for controlling attributes such as `version` and `exclude-result-prefixes`, etc.

Handling `xsl:import` this way is even more challenging, because of the need to respect import precedence. Basically, there are things you can do in a multi-module stylesheet that can't be done in a single-module stylesheet.

As for calls on `document()`, to find the calls accurately you will need to parse all the XPath expressions. If the argument to `document()` is a string literal, then in most cases it should be possible to generate a global variable containing the content of the referenced document, and replace the call on `document()` by a reference to the variable. (But take care with base URIs).

You haven't actually said what you're trying to achieve by transforming your stylesheets in this way. It's a lot of effort, and I can't see what it accomplishes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michael. First what I am trying to achive is the following. I have a number of java projects which all compile into azure functions. Basically each project is a parsers of a particular type of xml message. The parser function does xml -> json, json -> xml and xml -> html. In order to include the xsl stylesheets as resources for my java function I need to either supply a custom path resolver to my xslt transformer (I am using Saxon HE) or point to a single xsl stylesheet with no includes of external files. The root of the problem is the relative paths in the imports.

Comment: I actually have sovled the issue by adding a custom path resolver but was curious to see if I could do by embedding the css file content as well. Oh and I am aware of the issues you bring up concerning processing of xsl:include and imports. At the moment I am actually replacing all occurrances of xsl:import with xsl:include

Comment: Ideally I would like to have precompiled Saxon Templates object and use that in my transformation but I have no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: The standard `TransformerFactory.newTemplates(source)` method will construct a single compiled stylesheet by following all the `xsl:include` and `xsl:import` references. Saxon also has a configuration option to preload documents referenced using the `doc()` or `document()` function if the URI is statically known.

Answer (score 1):

If you want access CSS files via XSLT stylesheet, use `unparsed-text()` function instead of `document()` function.

https://www.cw3.org/TR/2017/REC-xpath-functions-31-20170321/#func-unparsed-text

`doument()` function assumes the target as XML file and returns the document-node. `unparsed-text()` function treats the target as text file and returns the whole contents as `xs:string`.

However you cannot use it XSLT version 1.0, instead yo should use XSLT 3.0 enabled processor such as Saxon HE.